# Update Labels caption with corresponding next column from listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 2 columns. One column is an organization name.  The next column is how much that organization charges per hour. I'm using a userform and I have a listbox and a label. The listbox show all values in column 1.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim lbtarget As MSForms.ListBox
Dim rngSource As Range

'Set reference to the range of data to be filled
Set rngSource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A125")

'Fill the listbox
Set lbtarget = Me.ListBox1
With lbtarget
    'Determine number of columns
    .ColumnCount = 1
    'Set column widths
    .ColumnWidths = "100"
    'Insert the range of data supplied
    .List = rngSource.Cells.Value
End With

End Sub
```

I want the label to correspond with the selected Item in the Listbox. So for example if I select Asset Management (Cell A2), I want the label to show the same row but the next column, $47.00 (Cell B2). Any help will be greatly appreciated. Have a good weekend!

Comment: This looks like VBA, not vb.net. If thats the case please retag

Answer (score 1):

Use the listboxes index to address the 2nd column of your range, i.e.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim Idx As Long

    Idx = ListBox1.ListIndex + 1
    Label1.Caption = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A18").Cells(Idx, 2)
End Sub
```